# How to fix disable validation in Dynamo-db against null / empty string?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to push the data to Dynamodb from node JS code.

I am getting the issue like

DynamoDB.DocumentClient should support empty string properties

does anyone knows how to disable validation in DynamoDB ?

Comment: The validation cannot be disabled.

Comment: @VishnuRanganathan did you find solution?

Comment: @AmodGokhale : yes , i have added the solution in section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding this we will be able to insert empty values to Dynamodb.

```
var dynamoDocClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region : 'us-west-2', convertEmptyValues : true });
```

Comment: convertEmptyValues will convert empty strings to NULL, then save it. Be careful that that is indeed what you want.

Comment: How to you achieve this in Java instead of Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**2020 May 18 Update:**

DynamoDB now supports empty string values for non-key attributes: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

In order to have consistent behavior, make sure that the client does *not* have `{ convertEmptyValues: true }`, or else these attributes will be saved as NULL as opposed to an empty string.