# AWS DynamoDB JAVA SKD converting null values to true

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using aws dynamo and Lambda services. 
In my lambda I'm trying to persist one item, but one of it's attributes is null. 
When it is persisted, on dynamoDb it is showed as TRUE. 
After some search, I've fount that in JS SKJ, this can be solved with 'convertEmptyValues':

```
var dynamoDocClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region : 'us-west-2', convertEmptyValues : true });
```

[How to fix disable validation in Dynamo-db against null / empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625681/how-to-fix-disable-validation-in-dynamo-db-against-null-empty-string)

Anyone could help me to achive this with JAVA?

Example code:

```
    private PutItemOutcome persistData(Table table, Item item) throws ConditionalCheckFailedException, Exception {

        return table
                .putItem(
                        new PutItemSpec().withItem(
                                new Item()
                                        .withPrimaryKey("id", "awsRequestId")
                                        .with("timestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
                                        .with("name", null)
                        ).withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD)
                );
    }
```